# Замена контента

Tags: jquery

В чем отличие в Jquery метода `replaceWith` от просто взять `id` или класс и присвоить им то значение через `val()`, что нам требуется? Что лучше? Или, точнее, как правильнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.replaceWith() - обвертка для свойства outerHTML DOM объекта

.html() - обвертка для свойства innerHTML DOM объекта

В остальном можно смотреть ответ [@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre). %)

Answer (score 3):

По-моему. это единственный метод "изменить" **сам элемент**, а не его содержимое, т.е. методы вроде [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) не заменяют селектируемый элемент

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div id='child'>
    </div>
</div>
```

В данном случае:

```
$('#parent').html('<p>some text</p>');
//эквивалентно
$('#child').replaceWith('<p>some text</p>');
```